# How closedxml.report IEnumerable extend vertical not horizontal

Tags: c#, closedxml, closedxml.report

I have data like :

```
    "materialFormingFee": [
        {
            "type": "Cover(盖)",
            "des": "ABS 757K+AS 118",
            "matching": "100%",
            "weight": "0",
            "ComponentWeight": 0,
            "materilPrice": 0,
            "shapingPrice": 0,
            "lossPrice": 0,
            "totalPrice": 0,
            "byProductWeight": "0",
            "holeNum": "8",
            "eqp": "海天160T",
            "WorkPrice": "0",
            "period": "0",
            "lossRate": "0",
            "efficiency": "0",
            "up": "0",
            "TonerUp": "0",
            "TonerQty": "0",
            "TonerAmt": 0,
            "TonerSpc": "F8756",
            "eqp_man_unit_up": 0,
            "eqp_fixed_unit_up": 0,
            "eqp_manager_unit_up": 0,
            "std_man_qty": "0"
        }....
    ]
```

and i define excel name `materialFormingFee` and use `{{item.propartyName}}`,like below photo :

[image]

but the result extend horizontal not vertical

[image]

I already read the information on the Github Wiki and the Website (https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know the point from [doc](
https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/Flat-tables)

> specifying a vertical table must have `at least two columns and two rows`

[image]

and the result by vertical : 
[image]